# Neo4j import tool with csv files: how to import labels column as list of labels

Tags: import, neo4j, label

I am importing some nodes and relationships as csv files using the neo4jImport tool and I have a column in my csv file that is a list of strings that are to be my node labels. Is it possible to do this? If so, what is the correct csv format for the list of strings? Will [string1, string2, ..., stringn] work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `neo4j-import` import tool:

The `:LABEL` column of the CSV file also supports multiple labels, separated by the provided array separated (default is `;`)

```
:LABELS
Label1;Label2
```